# How to call a possibly null returning sql function from C extension in PostgresQL

Tags: c, postgresql, sql-null

I'm writing a PostgresQL C extension and I'd like to call a sql function that can possibly return null value. I cannot use `DirectFunctionCall` family of functions, because they raise an error when called function that returns null.

More specifically my use case is as follows:
I want to call `to_regprocedure` to get an OID of a user provided function and call it if it exists and do nothing otherwise. Both `to_regprocedure` and user provided function can return null.

I tried `DirectFunctionCall`, but it raises an error.

I could probably use SPI, but have not tried that, because I'd rather avoid using it just for this single case.

Ideally, I'd like to have a function similar to `DirectFunctionCall` that does not raise an error when called function return null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some possible options to consider that avoid spi (but it is an option too):

1. Use COALESCE() allowing you to substitute a default value for a null returned from the called function.
2. Assuming you can't amend the exiting function, you could use a "wrapper function" to call the existing function passing through whatever arguments it needs. If the called function returns null or raises an error it returns something other than null. For example, if you want the wrapper function to return the text value 'error' when the called function returns null or raises an error, you can modify the wrapper function like this:

```
create or replace function my_wrapper_function(arg text) returns text language plpgsql as $$
begin
    begin
        return my_function(arg);
    exception when others then
        return 'error';
    end;
end
$$;
```

3. Use a `PG_TRY` block to catch the error raised by `DirectFunctionCall()` when the called function returns null allows you to handle the error and continue execution. In the `PG_CATCH` block, you can check whether the error was raised due to the called function returning null and clear the error if that is the case.